# How To share configurations between Two or more TRAC environments

Tags: configuration, share, trac, projects, issue-tracking

hope this is a good spot for my question,
for it i SW Related, but not code related.

We, in our company are using TRAC for Issue tracking and management of the Code links,
I am very satisfied by it, and like how it is working.

i have about several environments (1 per project) and every time we change a setting in the Configurations (e.g. Users & Permissions, Severity, Ticket types, etc...) we need to change all of them.

I Use
    `[inherit]`
    `file=../../../sharedTrac.ini`
and delete the shared parts from the file.

for the preferences, but i didn't find a way to share the Configurations.
this is bad for several reason and the head reason is that is "Bugs me !!!" :p

Can TRAC read its configurations from a central definition, and the data from a local DB?

**EDIT:**
I noticed all these configurations are in the `.db` file (sqlite file)...
Is there a Ready made tool to copy the configurations from DB to DB ?
or should i go ahead and analyse what should be copied and how ?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Note though, that local settings will always over-rule inherited ones, so you must delete them in your `<env>/conf/trac.ini` files to make central configuration effective.

Specifically to the part of configuration inside Trac db: No, there is no sync tool yet. Given that there was one for user accounts that is still a beta after years, there's not much interest. You should use the `trac-admin` command-line tool (as already advised here) or start to directly sync parts the db by means of own (Python) scripts or custom db syncronisation. For a start have a look at the [Trac db schema](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema).

Comment: good morning...
i might not explaind myself correctly... 
the config part is clear and done, i try to sync the
`user permissions`, `Ticket severity`, `Ticket Types` Etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this through command line. Just call appropriate "trac-admin" command for each instance. Example one-liner to add user profile:

```
for D in */; do trac-admin $D session add username "Full Name" user@email.com ; done
```

Comment: Nice batch work :) ...
it solve some manual work, but still, changes on one repository are not propogated to the other.  this only makes the typing shorter, which is good too... but not solving the problem.